# Origin of Unseelie Accord

Tags: the-dresden-files

Probably the most important law document in the "Dresden Files" universe is the ["Unseelie Accords](http://dresdenfiles.wikia.com/wiki/Unseelie_Accords)", which is similar to the Vienna Convention of Diplomatic Relations. According to linked page, it has been proposed by Queen Mab of Winter Court, and has been signed by most political players, including the Summer Court.

Yeah, thats the thing that bothers me: why Summer would sign something called **Unseelie** Accords ([Unseelie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifications_of_fairies#Seelie_and_Unseelie_Courts) relates to "dark faeries", associated with Winter, contrary to the Seelie ones associated with Summer) - Winter and Summer are in a state of cold (ha ha) war since times long before humanity and if compare it to real world Cold War, I have hard time imagine USSR signing "Washington Convention" or USA signing under "The Communist Treaty". I know that diplomacy is an [art of compromises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mare_Moscoviense), but such important document signed by Summer would be a display of weakness.

So, why Summer has signed this treaty under such "offensive" name?

Comment: There's not any question in there.  Mab wrote the Accords.  Is what you're asking whether Summer signed it, or why they would?

Comment: Updated - I'm interested why summer signed it under such offensive name

Comment: Summer and Winter oppose one another not because they hate each other or have opposing philosophies, but simply because it is in their nature to do so.  The analogy with our Cold War is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: Of course it is in their nature, which makes it even more weird, why would Summer let Winter to "score point" in the political game. It is as if hyenas and lions (two species that have in their nature to compete with each other) agreed to sign a "big cat treaty".

Comment: Hard to say whether the Sidhe would see it as Winter scoring points or not.  I don't see any obvious reason why they should.

Comment: Do we know if the "Unseelie accords" actually the proper name of the agreement and not just a short commonly-used version of it?  Like everyone calling it the "Treaty of Versailles" rather than the "Treaty of Peace between the Allied and Associated Powers and Germany".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There really isn't a lot of information on the origin of the Unseelie Accords in the books.  So I speculate.

Their intention seems to have been (seems, as Mab usually has at least 3 angles on everything) to broker peace or at least forced less aggression among the supernatural nations at large.  It does so not by banning hostility but by adding a large amount of rules lawyering, based on old notions of honor and hospitality.  Bureaucracy isn't usually that effective at anything, but I guess when it's designed by the most calculating mind we've met in the series thus far, and then imposed by that same being who excels at being very, very scary, even wizards sit up and pay attention.

This is a lot of lead up around the question posed.  It's nature though, is at the core of this.  The name of the Accords keeps Winter in everyone's minds, and politics rules the day.  That cold calculation is what Winter is all about.  It's *not* what Summer is all about though.  They may all be Fae and all love a good bargain, Summer's default mode may always be to counter Winter, but their goals and their methods of thinking are *not* the same.  If Titania thought a greater goal would be achieved by Mab's bizarre notions of peace, she wouldn't care what it was called, so long as the balance of power didn't shift (and Mab is crafty enough to calculate that balance of power into her planning).

Mab would write it because it sets the game of nations to her advantage, and that edge is what Winter is all about.  Titania would sign because peace would promote life, and life is what Summer is all about.

Comment: I really like this answer, really good point on Summer's and Winter's point of view.

Comment: I disagree with the last sentence; the heart of Winter may be ice, but the heart of Summer is an equally lifeless desert.  (I paraphrase; don't have the books to hand.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston - Titania's realm is never described or visited.  That said, I'd picture an endless and opressive jungle to be more fitting of Summer.  They are aligned with fire, but also with passion, and life unrestrained.  Deserts just bake you.  It might be better to say Summer would be all about life thriving (possibly without regard to consequence), and Winter is all about life surviving (survival of the fittest is really Mab's creed).

Comment: @HarryJohnston in "Summer Knight" Bob explains that if Summer would win a war, there "would be explosion of life, which is really great if you happened to be an Ebola virus"

Comment: @Yasskier: that would be a side-effect, I think, not a goal.  Titania's purpose is to protect mankind from Winter, not to destroy us.  Radhil, I can't find the quote I was looking for.  I'll post it if I do, but perhaps I was thinking of a different series.  (I think it was a metaphorical desert in any case, not a literal one.)

Answer (score 6):

**Because the name is not offensive.**

The majority of treaties that have been signed throughout history are named after the location of the signing itself. Such as: The [Camp David Accords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camp_David_Accords), The [Treaty of Warsaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Warsaw_(1970)) and the [Treaty of San Francisco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_San_Francisco).

In the case of this treaty, it was likely named based on the fact that the majority of the discussions took place in the Unseelie Court.

Sometimes a treaty is named after only one of the people it is responsible for such as in the case of hostilities between Pakistan and the Waziristan area tribals where we have a treaty named after only one of the parties, the [Waziristan Accord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waziristan_Accord).

Comment: Please note that in the last example (Wazaristan Accord) is arguably named on the side that actually gained more from it (including world-wide recognition). In other words - if its named after you, you gain.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that Summer would necessarily find that name offensive. It's really just a factual description of the agreement.

It is typical for such diplomatic agreements to be named after the place where they were signed or the group that wrote them in the first place. Since Mab wrote them, it's not hard to believe that she invited the first few signatories to her Court -- the Unseelie Court -- to sign them. Calling them the Unseelie Accords is just the most reasonable thing to pick.

It's not like the names Seelie and Unseelie are insults or derogatory. They're the formally correct adjectives for the two Fae Courts.

In top of that, my vague understanding is that the Accords, at least in the beginning, were conceived partly to minimize the bickering and fighting between denizens of the Nevernever so they could all cooperate in keeping the Outsiders out. Since Winter is on the front lines of that war, it would make sense to name such an agreement after their court, to remind everyone why they've signed.

(I'm not sure where I got that idea in my head, as I can't find it again; in any case, as far as I know every signatory to the Accords has shown to be an enemy of Nemesis at some point, even the Denarians.)

Comment: While "Seelie" and "Unseelie" are not derogatory descriptions, adding such name to important document means a bit "we are more important than you". In real world situations, such documents are usually written "on neutral ground". Well, one could argue that Titania is not as petty to fight over name.

Comment: I don't think the naming of the Warsaw Pact, for example, was meant to imply that Poland was the most important member of the USSR.

Comment: @HarryJohnston that is a bad example, because all members of the Warsaw Pact were on the same political side and it was supposed to symbol the unity behind the first country invaded by Nazis. Treaties between countries that are enemies are signed usually either on neutral ground or on the victor's home ground.Signing it on the Winter court (and naming it after it) *might* suggest that Winter is in this case a victor and Summer is forced to sign a treaty as a loser.

Comment: Seems to me you're thinking of peace treaties, which is a quite different kettle of miscellaneous swimming things.  (But even then the very first example I ran across when I went looking was the Treaty of Paris, signed after England's victory over France and Spain!)

Comment: OK, I guess I stand corrected then @HarryJohnston . Thanks for your input :)